How to read Oracle HCM HDL(.dat) file into pandas?
I have an Oracle HCM HDL(.dat) file containing data structured in a specific format, and I want to read it into pandas, perform anonymization on values on some of the columns and then save each section into its own CSV file and also convert back into same HDL format.
Here is the sample
METADATA|Worker|SourceSystemOwner|SourceSystemId|EffectiveStartDate|PersonNumber|StartDate|DateOfBirth|ActionCode
MERGE|Worker|EMP|HDL001|2001/09/08|HDL-1001|2001/09/08|1952/05/21|HIRE
MERGE|Worker|EMP|HDL002|2005/02/08|HDL-1002|2005/02/08|1966/04/21|HIRE

METADATA|PersonName|SourceSystemOwner|SourceSystemId|EffectiveStartDate|PersonId(SourceSystemId)|NameType|LegislationCode|Title|LastName|FirstName
MERGE|PersonName|EMP|HDL001_NME|2001/09/08|HDL001|GLOBAL|US|MR.|Wells|Christopher
MERGE|PersonName|EMP|HDL002_NME|2005/02/08|HDL002|GLOBAL|US|MRS.|Hugh|Lorraine

Documentation on Oracle HCM HDL file structure: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/tutorial-hdl-load-files/index.html#task_one
Could someone provide a Python code example or guidance on how to accomplish this task efficiently using pandas read_csv and to_csv?

import pandas as pd

# Read the data from the Oracle HCM HDL file
with open('data.hdl', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

# Initialize empty lists to store dataframes for each section
worker_data = []
person_name_data = []

# Process each line in the data
for line in data:
    line = line.strip().split('|')
    section = line[0]
    values = line[1:]

    # Convert the values into a dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame([values], columns=['SourceSystemOwner', 'SourceSystemId', 'EffectiveStartDate', 'PersonId', 'NameType', 'LegislationCode', 'Title', 'LastName', 'FirstName'])

    # Anonymize specific columns if it's the worker section
    if section == 'MERGE|Worker':
        # Perform anonymization on specific columns
        df['PersonNumber'] = df['PersonNumber'].apply(lambda x: 'Anon' + str(x))
    
    # Append the dataframe to the appropriate list
    if section == 'MERGE|Worker':
        worker_data.append(df)
    elif section == 'MERGE|PersonName':
        person_name_data.append(df)

# Concatenate dataframes for each section
worker_df = pd.concat(worker_data, ignore_index=True)
person_name_df = pd.concat(person_name_data, ignore_index=True)

# Save each section into its own CSV file
worker_df.to_csv('worker_data.csv', index=False)
person_name_df.to_csv('person_name_data.csv', index=False)

# Convert back into HDL format
with open('worker_data.csv', 'r') as file:
    worker_data_csv = file.readlines()

with open('person_name_data.csv', 'r') as file:
    person_name_data_csv = file.readlines()

# Write the data back into the HDL file
with open('output.hdl', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(worker_data_csv)
    file.writelines(person_name_data_csv)

Make sure to replace 'data.hdl' with the path to your Oracle HCM HDL file. This code assumes that the data in the HDL file is structured exactly as provided in the sample data. Adjustments may be necessary depending on the actual structure of your data.

Thanks @christin-babu for the code. Unfortunately, the code is not working as expected. The columns name varies for each Entity (Worker, PersonName)

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
